# The specified URL has an unsupported scheme. Only HTTP and HTTPS URLs are supported

Tags: ios, swift

My code is

```
let idx = (self.tappedIndexPath?.row)!
let pcs = self.sortedArray[idx]
let urlW = URL(string: ("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=\(String(describing: pcs.name))".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed))!)
let svm = SFSafariViewController.init(url: urlW!)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(svm, animated: true)
```

is crashing for this error:

> "The specified URL has an unsupported scheme. Only HTTP and HTTPS URLs are supported."

I do not understand the problem, my url is in https so why it is crashing?

Comment: Assign the url string to a string first and print that. You'll immediately see the problem. *Hint:* You are escaping too much. – (Does nobody learn how to *debug* anymore?)

Comment: If you print `urlW.scheme` what does it say it is?

Comment: @PhillipMills ok it said "nil"

Comment: @fisherM I said it five times. Please invest some time to find a solution for your problem, at least one hour. This is not a WhatsApp group. You didn't even print something before you posted your question. All your questions are the same style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is misleading. Too many percent escaped characters confuse the `URL(string` initializer.

The solution is to percent escape **only** the search query using the proper character set (`urlHostAllowed` is only for the host, the part between `://` and the following slash) and for safety add optional bindings:

```
let pcs = self.sortedArray[idx]
if let query = pcs.name.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed),
    let urlW = URL(string: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=" + query) {
       let svm = SFSafariViewController(url: urlW)
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(svm, animated: true)
} else {
    print("Bad URL")
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the error "Cannot call value of non-function type 'String'"

Comment: Where do you get the error? The code in my answer should not throw this error.

Comment: i get it in the line let urlW = URL(..)

Comment: What type does `sortedArray` contain? Or what is `pcs`?

Comment: var sortedArray: [EClass] = []

Comment: Have you declared somewhere a variable URL? There might be a clash with the `URL(string:` initializer.

Comment: i checked, only this if let imgUrl = URL(string:snapshotValue?["profile_pic"] as! String), possible is the cause of the error?

Comment: Where does this code come from? It's not part of the question.

Comment: you asked me if i declared somewhere an url, this code is in the same class but is in the viewDidLoad

Comment: No I meant a property or variable like `var URL : String`

Comment: I tested the URL creating code with an arbitrary string. It should work without an error